# Updating time in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I have two tables as follows:

```
CUST_HEAD:
Order_No
CreateDate

CUST_STAGE:
Order_no
CreateDate
```

Both the CreateDate fields are datetime type. I want to update the column CreateDate of table CUST_HEAD with the CreateDate of CUST_STAGE.

I have used the following block to do it:

```
DECLARE

CURSOR C1 IS
       select ORDER_NO, CREATEDATE FROM CUST_STAGE;
BEGIN

for i in c1
  LOOP

  UPDATE CUST_HEAD
  SET CREATEDATE = i.CREATEDATE
  where ORDER_NO = i.ORDER_NO;
  END LOOP;

END;
```

But after the update, it has not updated the time in the CUST_HEAD table and defaulted it to 12.00.00 in the CreateDate column.
How to update the datetime column both with date and time ?

Comment: Your code would set both the date and time components.  If there is a problem with the time, then it would appear to be in `CUST_STAGE`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your code would be resetting the time.  However, there is no need to use a cursor for this update, even in Oracle:

```
update cust_head
    set createdate = (select createdate from cust_stage cs where cs.order_no = cust_head.order_no)
    where order_no in (select order_no from cust_stage);
```